# Sending email using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email, import-from-excel

So the code below works if I manually add the email address in to `$Mail.To = ("XYZ@xxx.com")` but once I disable that and then pull from an excel column (**mgremail**) it gives me this error

```
There must be at least one name or contact group in the To, Cc, or Bcc box.At C:\Users\pshivam\Desktop\Scripts\test.ps1:60 char:5
+ $Mail.Send()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

**My code:**

```
Import-Module ac*
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\pshivam\Desktop\Scripts\User.csv
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String “Newuser1” -AsPlainText -Force 

foreach($item in $csv){
$mgrmail = $item.mgremail
$sam =$item.Username
$displayname = (Get-ADUser $sam -Properties displayname).displayname
    ##name
    $nameTitle = "Name: "
    $Name = (Get-ADUser $sam -Properties cn).name
    #upn
    $upnTitle = "User Logon: "
    $UPN = (Get-ADUser $sam -Properties userprincipalname).userprincipalname
    $ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
    $mail = $ol.createItem(0)
    $Mail.To=($mgrmail)
    #$Mail.To=("XYZ@xxx.com")
    $Mail.Subject="TEST"
    $Mail.Body = "Hi, 

    "+ $nameTitle, $displayname, "
    " + $upnTitle, $upn + "
TEST
    "
    $Mail.Send()
}
```

Comment: It's a lot easier to just use `Send-MailMessage`.

Comment: You should test for empty values.  `If (-not $mgrmail) { }`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script a while back that was used by a tier 1 team that would generate emails in Outlook for them when they were helping an end user. It didn't send the email (for workflow reasons) but it would be simple enough to make it send. This should at least give you something to go off of for adding recipients to an email in an automated manner.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$MailItem = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$MailItem.GetInspector.Activate()|Out-Null
$Signature = $MailItem.HTMLBody
$CCAddr = $MailItem.Recipients.add($User.email)
$CCAddr.Type = 2
$CCAddr.Resolve()|Out-Null
$MailItem.Recipients|?{$_.Type -eq 1}|%{$_.Delete()}
$ToAddr = $MailItem.Recipients.add($Item.MgrEmail)
$ToAddr.Resolve()|Out-Null
$MailItem.Subject="Task description"
$MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName='Team DL'
$MailItem.HTMLBody = $HTMLBody + $Signature
$MailItem.GetInspector.Activate()|Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable Outlook,MailItem
```

I had defined a here string containing the HTML for the body of the email previously in the script as `$HTMLBody`. This would open a new email, initialize it, add the team's distribution list to the CC line, add the user to the To line (updated to reflect your `$Item.MgrEmail`), set who the email was sent as so that it came from the team's DL, and would retain the user's signature. It worked really well, except that the Send As option in the GUI didn't accurately reflect the value I set the email to be sent from (it still sent properly, from their DL, it just showed their personal alias in the GUI).

You could obviously omit some things, but I figured I would offer this up since I used it and know it works.

Answer (score 0):

Very convoluted code example.  Here's something much simpler:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\User.csv

ForEach ($item in $csv)
{
    $User = Get-ADUser $item.Username -Properties @('userprincipalname','displayname')

    $Params=@{
        ErrorAction='Stop'

        To = $item.mgremail
        From = 'Example@test.com'
        SmtpServer = 'fwdhost@test.com'
        Subject = 'Test'
        Body = @"
Hi,
    Name: $($User.displayname)
    User Logon: $($User.userprincipalname)

Regards,
    TEST
"@
    }

    Try {
        Send-MailMessage @Params
    } Catch {
        Write-Host ('Failed to send email. ' + $PSItem.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor White
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShivPatel Make sure the role is enabled on the server you intend to point at.  Here's [a help topic](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/9c99624f-4379-4f19-85a3-5e2c58012343/how-to-find-smtp-address-on-exchange-server?forum=exchangesvradminlegacy) on the subject

Comment: What if I dont have access to enable this role on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a simple SMTP send:

```
$smtpserver="smtp server"
$from = "email address"
$to = "email address"
$subject = "subject"
$body = "What ever you want...."
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “password” -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($from, $secpasswd)
Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $smtpserver -Credential $creds -Usessl true -from $from -to $to -subject $subject -attachment $body
```